# Request user data after logging in by facebook

Tags: php, ajax, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hear is my php code that trying to login by Facebook

```
public function fb_login(){
    
    $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
        'app_id' => '<app id>',
        'app_secret' => '<app secret>',
        'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
    ]);

    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
    $permissions = ['public_profile', 'user_friends', 'publish_actions', 'email', 'user_about_me', 'user_birthday']; // optional
    $data['login_url'] = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://localhost/trada-backend/index.php/facebook_login/fb_callback', $permissions);
    // $data = json_encode($data['login_url']);
    /*$this->load->view('home',$data);*/
    echo json_encode($data);
    // echo $data;
}


public function fb_callback(){
    $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
        'app_id' => '<app id>',
        'app_secret' => '<app secret>',
        'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
    ]);

    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
    try {
        $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        // When Graph returns an error
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        // When validation fails or other local issues
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
        }

    if (isset($accessToken)) {
        // Logged in!
        $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;
        $session = $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'];

        $fbApp = new Facebook\FacebookApp('<app id>', '<app secret>');
        $request = new Facebook\FacebookRequest($fbApp, $accessToken, 'GET', '/me', 
            array('fields' => 'picture{url},id,name,birthday,email,link'));


        try {
            $response = $fb->getClient()->sendRequest($request);
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        // When Graph returns an error
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        // When validation fails or other local issues
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
        }

        $graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
        /* handle the result */
//      $message = 'User name: ' . $graphNode['name'];
        $data = array (
            'id' => $graphNode['id'],
            'birthday' => $graphNode['birthday'],
            'email' => $graphNode['email'],
            'link' => $graphNode['link'],
            'user_name' => $graphNode['name'],
            'is_logged_in' => 1,
            'profile_pic_link' => json_decode($graphNode['picture'])->url
        );

        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        /*redirect(base_url().'user/index');*/
        echo json_encode($data);
        // Now you can redirect to another page and use the
        // access token from $_SESSION['facebook_access_token']
    }
}
```

Here is my Ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost/trada-backend/index.php/Facebook_login/fb_login",
    success : function(url_response){
        var url = JSON.parse(url_response);
        /*alert(url.login_url);*/
        $('a.btn-facebook').attr('href', url.login_url);
    }
});
```

In my Ajax, I try to get the url from fb_login() in php in order to get the permission from user but after that I want to request this which inside fb_callback()

```
$data = array (
        'id' => $graphNode['id'],
        'birthday' => $graphNode['birthday'],
        'email' => $graphNode['email'],
        'link' => $graphNode['link'],
        'user_name' => $graphNode['name'],
        'is_logged_in' => 1,
        'profile_pic_link' => json_decode($graphNode['picture'])->url
    );
```

However, the fb_callback() is called inside my fb_login()

```
$data['login_url'] = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://localhost/trada-backend/index.php/facebook_login/fb_callback', $permissions);
```

So, how can I retrieve my desired data ? Thanks in advance

### **SOLVED**

So I have figured out 1 way to deal with this.
First I put my desired data at fb_callback() to a cookie and then send this cookie to my frontend page

```
$data = json_encode($data_session);
setcookie('facebook', $data, time()+1, "/");
include('http://localhost/trada-frontend/index.html');
redirect('http://localhost/trada-frontend/index.html');
```

In my js file I get the data from the cookie by seperating cookie name and its data and decode uri the data

```
var fb_data= document.cookie;
if(fb_data != null){
    var cookieParts = fb_data.match(/^([^=]+)=(.*)$/);
    var cookie_name = cookieParts[1];
    var decode = decodeURIComponent(cookieParts[2]);
    var fb = JSON.parse(decode);
   
}
```

Comment: Remove personal facebook auth keys/codes please

Comment: sorry but which one, I'm kind of new at this

Comment: well if you know the term "secret", then know that you should not post this value... So all of the secrets at least

Comment: ahh ok thanks alot